# Clusterability Tests in Social Sciences

Tags: clustering

There are many cluster tendency tests (clusterability tests), such as Hopkins statistic, Visual Assessment of Tendency, and SigClust. Still, I haven't seen many examples of these tests being used in social science cluster analysis.

Do I have to perform these tests? Does it make sense to do a cluster analysis even if my data doesn't pass the clusterability tests? If it depends, what are the cases where a cluster analysis is still meaningful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various different concepts of what a "cluster" is, and whatever you do should depend on the nature and meaning of your data and the aim of clustering. You may want to read this: https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.02059

The Handbook of Cluster Analysis (where this is from) also has a chapter on hypthesis tests in cluster analysis, written by the SigClust authors. All clustering tests are based on null hypotheses formalising specific meanings of "data are homogeneous/not clustered" that may or may not be relevant in a specific application.

Particularly, in many situations it is useful to cluster observations in order to have homogeneous subgroups that are better to handle (for example in market segmentation, if a company wants to address specific segments of customers) even if the dataset is pretty homogeneous without clusters that are clearly separated from each other, in which case a clusterability test may not reject homogeneity.

On the other hand, it may happen that data are significantly different from a non-clustering null hypothesis due to structural issues such as nonlinearity or autocorrelation, even if there are no meaningful clusters in the data, see the discussion here:
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11222-015-9566-5

This means that neither is a non-rejection of homogeneity an indication that data should definitely not be clustered, nor does a rejection mean that clustering is meaningful for sure, which may be one reason why these tests are not so often used.

That said, these tests are informative in the sense that if you can't reject a rather simple homogeneity null model, not too much meaning apart from being homogeneous should be attributed to the clusters, and on the other hand obviously you can't claim a homogeneity model fits the data well if you reject it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have read the chapter you recommended. Your last two paragraphs are especially helpful because textbooks or handbooks in cluster analysis do not necessarily mention this point. By the way, if you happen to know the answer to the question below, I would appreciate it if you could tell me your opinion.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/526258/hopkins-statistic-in-clustering